# How to implement shared element transition between two viewholder types in a recyclerview?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, shared-element-transition

I have a recycler view that displays images . There are two different layouts: grid layout and detailed layout. In the grid layout, the view holder displays small images as a list. In the detailed layout, the view holder is changed and the image becomes slightly bigger with some text below it.

There is a button in fragment, that when clicked changes the view holder type rendered by the adapter.

Now, I want to animate the image from normal list layout to detail layout when the layout is toggled. Is this possible with shared element transitions ? or should I use some other animation to animate between the two view holders ?